# passing parameters to jquery ui dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog, this

I use `.data` like this to pass the id of the textbox that calls the dialog

```
$("#<%=txtDirProprio.ClientID%>").focus(function() 
{
         $("#<%=dialog.ClientID%>").dialog( "open" ).data("id","#<%=txtDirProprio.ClientID%>");
         return false;
});
```

here is the code for the dialog

```
 $("#<%=dialog.ClientID%>").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                show: "blind",
                hide: "explode",
                width: 800,
                height:200,
                modal: true,
                buttons: 
                {
                    "Ajouter": function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        StringBuilderDir($( this ).data("id"));
                    },
                    "Vider": function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        $( $( this ).data("id") ).val("")
                    },
                    "Canceler": function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                },
                open: function() 
                { 
                    var dir = $( $( this ).data("id") ).val().split("-");
                    if(dir[0] != "")
                    {
                        $("#<%=dd_dialog_directionvp.ClientID%> option").each(function(index) 
                        {
                            if ($("#<%=dd_dialog_directionvp.ClientID()%> option")[index].text == dir[0]) 
                            {
                                $("#<%=dd_dialog_directionvp.ClientID()%>  option")[index].selected = true;
                            }
                        })
                     }
                 }
                 });
```

So `$  ( this ).data("id")` returns the id of the textbox. It works fine except in the open function. The id is undefined

Why it works in the functions for the buttons but not in the open function. It looks like it's not the same 'this'

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$("#<%=txtDirProprio.ClientID%>").focus(function() 
{
         $("#<%=dialog.ClientID%>").data("id","#<%=txtDirProprio.ClientID%>").dialog( "open" );
         return false;
});
```

Have to set the data first before calling `.dialog('open');`

Comment: Thank you! It works. I was on this for an hour, you took 30 seconds lol. But I don't understand. Why it wasn't working in the open function?

Comment: It wasn't working because when you call .dialog('open') the dialog box is opened and the open function is executed, then it returns jQuery and the next method .data() is called, setting the data. So because the open function executes before the data is set, it's not available on open ;)

Comment: What happends if you want to add more then one parameter?

Comment: You just use jQuery's chainability and do something like `$('.selector').data('foo',1).data('bar',2).dialog('open')` or alternatively pass your params in as an object `$('.selector').data('params',{foo:1,bar:2}).dialog('open')`

Comment: I actually came here for unrelated reason but it's helpful to know that `$(this)` inside `dialog()` refers to the container element.  In my case I was trying to pass data to ajax call inside button click so needed to assign `var self = this` inside click event and then `$(self).data('foo');` inside ajax callback